# Error when using map for Html's select, option

Tags: html, reactjs

Aren't the following two codes the same code?

But when using map I got a this error `caught TypeError: size.option.map is not a function`

```
 <select id="size">
          <option value="">--pleae choose a size--</option>
          <option value="">{size.option.small}</option>
          <option value="">{size.option.medium}</option>
          <option value="">{size.option.large}</option>
          <option value="">{size.option.xlarge}</option>
          <option value="">{size.option.xxlarge}</option>
        </select>
```

```
        <select id="size">
          <option value="">--pleae choose a size--</option>
          {size.option.map((s) => (
            <option value={s}>{s}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

[image]

[image]

my json

Comment: please share the code, 
are you mapping over the items array?
you can also use 
size?.option?.map(()=><option></option>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size.option` is an object, not an array therefore the `map` method is not callable. To iterate over an object you can use `Object.keys/values/entries`. For example:

```
<select id="size">
    <option value="">--pleae choose a size--</option>
    {Object.entries(size.option).map(([key, value]) => (
        <option key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

Don't forget you must provide a [`key` prop](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) when rendering arrays.